# How can I use the 'shallow: true' option with 'router.replace' in Next.js 13?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Does anyone has a solution for using shallow: true, when using router.replace? im working with next 13, in this version i have not found anything that works like shallow.

I want a way to do the same thing that shallow with useRouter does

Comment: [The docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating#shallow-routing) say `replace` takes an options object including `shallow` (see also [the code](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/v13.4.4/packages/next/src/shared/lib/router/router.ts#L1050) and [the options interface](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/v13.4.4/packages/next/src/shared/lib/router/router.ts#L65)).

Comment: export interface NavigateOptions {
    forceOptimisticNavigation?: boolean;
} replace(href: string, options?: NavigateOptions): void; i am using router from next/navigate

Comment: What's your use case?

Answer (score 0):

I think they made it automatic. So if you're actually going to a new route it'll take you there, if you're just adding things to the querystring or hash, it'll add them shallow.

If you want to enforce shallow replace, they seem to be recommending using the `window.history.replaceState`, but I had problems with that: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating#windowhistoryreplacestate